# Multiple context for undo/redo

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a procedure for undo/redo with entity framework.

I thought of creating a class like this:

```
public class multiContext
{
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public undoEntities _context { get; set; }
}
```

and for each modification create a new multiContext

```
private void btnSendB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     multiContext nContext = new multiContext { _id = multiContextManager.getEntityID(listEntities), _context = new undoEntities};
     listEntities.Add(nContext);
     foreach (TB1 item in gridA.SelectedItems)
     {
         item.Status = "B";

         nContext._context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
         nContext._context.SaveChanges();
     }

     refreshGrids();
 }
```

but the problem is that when i SaveChanges(), it change all the context in the list.

how can I save only the actual.

thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What is "the actual"? What do you want to be able to undo and when? (Before or after saving). Whatever it is, you can't save part of a context.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this same idea. You have to store each modification in a separate context in stacks for Undo then Redo. Before adding it in, call

```
this.DBContext.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

Then when you get it out of the undo or redo stack you just have to call this.DBContext.SaveChanges() then reload the textboxes with the new context.